Python: Merge two dataframes on certain columns using the excel equivalent of index/match
I'm trying to replicate an excel type of "index/match" in python.
I have two dfs.
df1:



RIC
Sector Code
SP500
SP400
SP600




FI
40
SP500




BRBR
30

SP400



XPEL
25


SP600



df2: (contains lookup table)



Code
Name
SP400
SP500
SP600




25
Consumer Discretionary
.SPMDCD
.SPSMCD
.SPLRCD


30
Consumer Staples
.SPMDCS
.SPSMCS
.SPLRCS


10
Energy
.SPMDCE
.SPSMCE
.SPNY


40
Financials
.SPMDCF
.SPSMCF
.SPSY


35
Health Care
.SPMDCA
.SPSMCA
.SPXHC


20
Industrials
.SPMDCI
.SPSMCI
.SPLRCI


45
Information Technology
.SPMDCT
.SPSMCT
.SPLRCT


15
Materials
.SPMDCM
.SPSMCM
.SPLRCM


50
Telecommunication Services
.SPMDCL
.SPSMCL
.SPLRCL


55
Utilities
.SPMDCU
.SPSMCU
.SPLRCU



Desired Result: (Adds the result to df1)



RIC
Sector Code
SP500
SP400
SP600
RESULT SP500
RESULT SP400
RESULT SP600




FI
40
SP500


.SPSMCF




BRBR
30

SP400


.SPMDCS



XPEL
25


SP600


.SPLRCD



I tried
merged_df = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['Sector Code'], right_on=['Code'], how='left'). 
This combined df1 and df2, but it give me every match (SP500, SP400, and SP600) instead of just the one match for each.

This Code is Most Efficient for huge Datasets.
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([
 {'RIC': 'FI', 'Sector Code': 40, 'SP500': 'SP500', 'SP400': '', 'SP600': ''},
 {'RIC': 'BRBR', 'Sector Code': 30, 'SP400': 'SP400', 'SP500': '', 'SP600': ''},
 {'RIC': 'XPEL', 'Sector Code': 25, 'SP400': '', 'SP500': '', 'SP600': 'SP600'}])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
 'Code': [25, 30, 10, 40, 35, 20, 45, 15, 50, 55],
 'Name': ['Consumer Discretionary', 'Consumer Staples', 'Energy', 'Financials', 
           'Health Care', 'Industrials', 'Information Technology', 'Materials', 
           'Telecommunication Services', 'Utilities'],
 'SP400': ['.SPMDCD', '.SPMDCS', '.SPMDCE', '.SPMDCF', '.SPMDCA', '.SPMDCI', 
           '.SPMDCT', '.SPMDCM', '.SPMDCL', '.SPMDCU'],
 'SP500': ['.SPSMCD', '.SPSMCS', '.SPSMCE', '.SPSMCF', '.SPSMCA', '.SPSMCI', 
           '.SPSMCT', '.SPSMCM', '.SPSMCL', '.SPSMCU'],
 'SP600': ['.SPLRCD', '.SPLRCS', '.SPNY', '.SPSY', '.SPXHC', '.SPLRCI', 
           '.SPLRCT', '.SPLRCM', '.SPLRCL', '.SPLRCU']})

"""
print(df1)
    RIC  Sector Code  SP500  SP400  SP600
0    FI           40  SP500              
1  BRBR           30         SP400       
2  XPEL           25                SP600

print(df2)

   Code                        Name    SP400    SP500    SP600
0    25      Consumer Discretionary  .SPMDCD  .SPSMCD  .SPLRCD
1    30            Consumer Staples  .SPMDCS  .SPSMCS  .SPLRCS
2    10                      Energy  .SPMDCE  .SPSMCE    .SPNY
3    40                  Financials  .SPMDCF  .SPSMCF    .SPSY
4    35                 Health Care  .SPMDCA  .SPSMCA   .SPXHC
5    20                 Industrials  .SPMDCI  .SPSMCI  .SPLRCI
6    45      Information Technology  .SPMDCT  .SPSMCT  .SPLRCT
7    15                   Materials  .SPMDCM  .SPSMCM  .SPLRCM
8    50  Telecommunication Services  .SPMDCL  .SPSMCL  .SPLRCL
9    55                   Utilities  .SPMDCU  .SPSMCU  .SPLRCU
"""
sp_cols = [col for col in df2.filter(like='SP')]
res_dict ={}
for col in sp_cols :
    res_dict[f'RESULT_{col}'] = df1['Sector Code'].apply(
        lambda d : df2.set_index('Code').loc[d,col] if d in df2['Code'].tolist() else np.nan
        
        )
    #print(res_dict[f'RESULT_{col}'])
df1_join_res_dict = df1.join(pd.DataFrame(res_dict))
print(df1_join_res_dict.to_string())
"""
   RIC  Sector Code  SP500  SP400  SP600 RESULT_SP400 RESULT_SP500 RESULT_SP600
0    FI           40  SP500                    .SPMDCF      .SPSMCF        .SPSY
1  BRBR           30         SP400             .SPMDCS      .SPSMCS      .SPLRCS
2  XPEL           25                SP600      .SPMDCD      .SPSMCD      .SPLRCD

"""


You can use .mask to remove the values from the merged results.  The filled value of the columns SP500, SP400, SP600 can be used as mask for the columns SP400_Result, SP500_Result, SP600_Result.
The following code assumes you have empty strings as the empty values in df1.
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([
 {'RIC': 'FI', 'Sector Code': 40, 'SP500': 'SP500', 'SP400': '', 'SP600': ''},
 {'RIC': 'BRBR', 'Sector Code': 30, 'SP500': '', 'SP400': 'SP400', 'SP600': ''},
 {'RIC': 'XPEL', 'Sector Code': 25, 'SP500': '', 'SP400': '', 'SP600': 'SP600'}])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
 'Code': [25, 30, 10, 40, 35, 20, 45, 15, 50, 55],
 'Name': ['Consumer Discretionary', 'Consumer Staples', 'Energy', 'Financials', 
           'Health Care', 'Industrials', 'Information Technology', 'Materials', 
           'Telecommunication Services', 'Utilities'],
 'SP400': ['.SPMDCD', '.SPMDCS', '.SPMDCE', '.SPMDCF', '.SPMDCA', '.SPMDCI', 
           '.SPMDCT', '.SPMDCM', '.SPMDCL', '.SPMDCU'],
 'SP500': ['.SPSMCD', '.SPSMCS', '.SPSMCE', '.SPSMCF', '.SPSMCA', '.SPSMCI', 
           '.SPSMCT', '.SPSMCM', '.SPSMCL', '.SPSMCU'],
 'SP600': ['.SPLRCD', '.SPLRCS', '.SPNY', '.SPSY', '.SPXHC', '.SPLRCI', 
           '.SPLRCT', '.SPLRCM', '.SPLRCL', '.SPLRCU']})

merged_df = df1.merge(
    df2, 
    left_on=['Sector Code'], 
    right_on=['Code'],
    how='left',
    suffixes=['', '_Result']
).drop(columns=['Code', 'Name'])

# these orders must match
cols_left = [ 'SP500', 'SP400', 'SP600']
cols_right = ['SP500_Result', 'SP400_Result', 'SP600_Result']

merged_df.loc[:, cols_right] = merged_df.loc[:, cols_right].mask(
    merged_df.loc[:, cols_left].eq('').values, '')


I truly appreciate your help. The merged_df is a bit off, however. For instance, FI is in the SP500 with a sector code of 40. It's showing up on the merged_df in the SP400_Results column... could it possibly be because the order is in df1 is different than the order in df2?

Ah, the order of the columns is bad.  I will fix it

It looks like a melt -> merge -> pivot would do the trick, then join back to the original:
out = df1.join(df1
 .reset_index().melt(['index', 'RIC', 'Sector Code'])
 .merge(df2.melt(['Code', 'Name']),
        left_on=['Sector Code', 'value'],
        right_on=['Code', 'variable'], how='left')
 .pivot(index='index', columns='variable_x', values='value_y')
 .add_prefix('RESULT ')
)

Output:
    RIC  Sector Code  SP500  SP400  SP600 RESULT SP400 RESULT SP500 RESULT SP600
0    FI           40  SP500    NaN    NaN          NaN      .SPSMCF          NaN
1  BRBR           30    NaN  SP400    NaN      .SPMDCS          NaN          NaN
2  XPEL           25    NaN    NaN  SP600          NaN          NaN      .SPLRCD

Variant if your empty cells are empty strings:
out = df1.join(df1
 .reset_index().melt(['index', 'RIC', 'Sector Code'])
 .merge(df2.melt(['Code', 'Name']),
        left_on=['Sector Code', 'value'],
        right_on=['Code', 'variable'], how='left')
 .pivot_table(index='index', columns='variable_x', values='value_y',
              aggfunc='first', fill_value='')
 .add_prefix('RESULT ')
)

Output:
    RIC  Sector Code  SP500  SP400  SP600 RESULT SP400 RESULT SP500 RESULT SP600
0    FI           40  SP500                                 .SPSMCF             
1  BRBR           30         SP400             .SPMDCS                          
2  XPEL           25                SP600                                .SPLRCD


Assuming you have the followng dataframes:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'RIC':['FI','BRBR','XPEL'],
    'Sector Code':[40,30,20],
    'SP500':['SP500',np.nan,np.nan],
    'SP400':[np.nan,'SP400',np.nan],
    'SP600':[np.nan,np.nan,'SP600']
})

and
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'code':[25,30,10,40,35,20,45,15,50,55],
    'Name':['Consumer Discretionary','Consumer Staples','Energy','Financials',
            'Health Care','Industrials','Information','Materials',
            'Telecommunication Services','Utilities'],
    'SP400':['.SPMDCD','.SPMDCS','.SPMDCE','.SPMDCF','.SPMDCA','.SPMDCI',
             '.SPMDCT','.SPMDCM','.SPMDCL','.SPMDCU'],
    'SP500':['.SPSMCD','.SPSMCS','.SPSMCE','.SPSMCF','.SPSMCA','.SPSMCI',
             '.SPSMCT','.SPSMCM','.SPSMCL','.SPSMCU'],
    'SP600':['.SPLRCD','.SPLRCS','.SPNY','.SPSY','.SPXHC','.SPLRCI',
             '.SPLRCT','.SPLRCM','.SPLRCL','.SPLRCU']
})

We beign with the following function to look up the values from df2. This function takes a row from df1 and the name of the SP column as input. If the SP index is not NaN (indicating a valid index), it looks up the corresponding value in df2 using the sector code and SP index, and returns it. If the SP index is NaN, it returns NaN.
def lookup_result(row, sp_col):
    sector_code = row['Sector Code']
    sp_index = row[sp_col]
    if not pd.isna(sp_index):
        return df2.loc[df2['code'] == sector_code, sp_index].values[0]
    else:
        return np.nan

We then iterate over the SP columns in df1 starting from the third column (index 2) because the first two columns are not SP indices. For each SP column, we extract the name of the SP index and apply the lookup_result function to each row of df1. The result is stored in the corresponding result column in df1.
result_columns = ['RESULT SP500', 'RESULT SP400', 'RESULT SP600']
for col in df1.columns[2:]:
    sp_col_name = col.split()[-1]
    df1[result_columns[df1.columns.get_loc(col)-2]] = df1.apply(lambda row: lookup_result(row, col), axis=1)

At the end, you should be left with:


I would rather not have the complication of another function. I really appreciate your post

Sorry. I just realized i placed a 20 instead of 25 in df1. Another way you can do it is to loop through df1.
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    sec_code = row['Sector Code']
    sp_code = ','.join([row[col] for col in ['SP500', 'SP400', 'SP600'] if not pd.isnull(row[col])])
    df1.loc[index, f'Result_{sp_code}'] = df2[df2['code'] == sec_code][sp_code].values[0]

Here i am looping through each row of df1 and grabbing the sector code and storing it in sec_code and then grabbing the non null string as the sp_code. then i am using the .loc method to assign a new column and new value based on sec_code and sp_code. I used the join method so that it would return the string instead of a list containing the string (just for simplicity). Hope this gives the desired output.

If you would like to remove the NaN's then:
df1 = df1.fillna('')

You can place a space or no space in between the ''

This has been an elegant solution. Thank you!
